# HttpWebResponse and encoding (weird characters)

Tags: c#, encoding, httpwebresponse

My problem is that when I send POST to form, then they're wrong characters.

I send extended ASCII:

> █████████

after POST I get:

> –“â–ˆ â–„â–“â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ

My code:

```
req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://forum.com/);
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
    req.Referer = "http://www.google.com/";

    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.CookieContainer = _cookieJar;
    req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

    byte[] bytedata =
        Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes("subject=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(subject.Replace("_", " ")) +
                           "&description=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(description));

    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("oh noes...");
    }
                break;
```

Encoding on site is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: You say "after post" you get the weird characters. Do you mean that the server interprets the characters that way? Or that your client, when you read the response, gets the weird characters. Have you examined the `bytedata` array to verify that the bytes you're sending are ISO-8859-1? What you say you're receiving looks an awful lot like UTF-8 to me. . .

Comment: Maybe another example. I have string like this: █████████ & I hate extended ASCII ... Then I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode that text. I get somtheing like this: %e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88%e2%96%88+%26+I+hate+extended+ASCII ... It's wrong. It should be like this (I read it using fiddler and google chrome): %26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B%26%239608%3B+%26+I+hate+extended+ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DID IT:

```
private string Encode(string text)
        {
            text = HTMLEncodeSpecialChars(text);
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);
        }

        public string HTMLEncodeSpecialChars(string text)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                if (c > 127) // special chars
                    sb.Append(String.Format("&#{0};", (int)c));
                else
                    sb.Append(c);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```